# Mantener la alineación en un Navbar Bootstrap 5

Tags: bootstrap-5, navbar

Tengo un navbar que contiene: el elemento navbar-toggler en la izquierda, una imagen al centro y un ícono en la derecha. Mientras la pantalla sea menor de 992px va todo bien, con la imagen centrada. Pero cuando es mayor a 992 px, la imagen se coloca inmediatamente al lado del icono, perdiendo el centro. ¿Hay forma de mantenerla centrada?

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-primary " data-bs-theme="dark">   
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" style="border:2px solid white;" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
       <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    
    <img src="img/logo.png" class="logo">
    
    <div class="contenedor_icono">
       <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-person-circle" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
           <path d="M11 6a3 3 0 1 1-6 0 3 3 0 0 1 6 0z"/>
           <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M0 8a8 8 0 1 1 16 0A8 8 0 0 1 0 8zm8-7a7 7 0 0 0-5.468 11.37C3.242 11.226 4.805 10 8 10s4.757 1.225 5.468 2.37A7 7 0 0 0 8 1z"/>
       </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2):

He probado tu código y lo único que le modifiqué fue la clase `navbar-expand-lg`. Así, se lograría el efecto que deseas. El código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```html
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <nav class="navbar bg-primary " data-bs-theme="dark">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" style="border:2px solid white;" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
          <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    
        <img src="img/logo.png" class="logo">
    
        <div class="contenedor_icono">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-person-circle" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
            <path d="M11 6a3 3 0 1 1-6 0 3 3 0 0 1 6 0z" />
            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M0 8a8 8 0 1 1 16 0A8 8 0 0 1 0 8zm8-7a7 7 0 0 0-5.468 11.37C3.242 11.226 4.805 10 8 10s4.757 1.225 5.468 2.37A7 7 0 0 0 8 1z" />
          </svg>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, no es lo que necesitaba, ya que siempre está visible el boton del navbar-toggler en cualquier ancho de pantalla. Igual me fué útil